# How can I use characters like ö and é in konva.Text?

Tags: konvajs

How can I use characters like ö and é in konva.Text?

Comment: Bert - could you explain further what issues you are having - there are lots of people here ready and able to help but it is polite to be a little more specific in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried [`konva.Text`](https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Text.html) within a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/64Love07/1/

Such special characters could be directly put in plain texts and actually I am still not sure what challenges within your situation.
Addtionally, some extra information could be helpful if this demo included answer still could not solve your problem perfectly.

Comment: Hi, actually - i mean how can I use specials characters with the format like &#8730; in KonvaJS.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.fromCharCode(insert_code_here)` to have text with these special characters.

For example, set the `text` attribute to `String.fromCharCode(8730)` to have &#8730; in the Konva text.

To produce "ö and é" use:

```
String.fromCharCode(246) + " and " + String.fromCharCode(233)
```